# unset session in smarty

Tags: php, session, smarty, unset

After I insert data to database I will set a session and then redirect page to another page,
on another page I will show a message if session was set in smarty, everything is ok.

```
{if $smarty.session.insert===true}
      Thanks
{/if}
```

Now how can I unset the session after I print my message ?

Comment: How about just dropping unset($var); below your print message?

Comment: @DarylGill `unset` is not a Smarty tag, I cannot use this in smarty, when I use `{unset($smarty.session.insert)}` I get an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldnt do that in template and smarty hasn't function for this. 
However, if you really have to do it, the only way around I see could be:

```
{php}
    unset($_SESSION['insert']);
{/php}
```

Anything you put between {php} tags will be run by smarty as regular php script.

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't do that from a template, do that in PHP like below.

```
unset($_SESSION['session_var_name']);
```

If you really want to do it in smart, Have you tried `{$smarty.session.message|unset}` 
I don't know if it works, but it may be worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

Smarty is a template engine. It is **not** supposed to handle session variables. You'll have to do `unset($_SESSION['...'])` in your PHP script, outside Smarty.

Answer (score 0):

In your php file where you are displaying smarty template, unset it after the display function.

```
if(isset($_POST['postdata'])) {
  $_SESSION['insert'] = 'success';
}

$smarty->display('test.html');
unset($_SESSION['insert']);
```

In your template file

```
{if isset($smarty.session.insert)}
  {$smarty.session.insert}
{/if}
```